Zuma inspired game heuristic and successors
I have a university assignment to design an admissible heuristic and reduce the number of successors for a game inspired by Zuma. The game features a line of colored balls (colors: 1, 2, 3, 4) and some ammo. If there are three or more consecutive balls of the same color, they are removed from the line. This removal can trigger cascading effects. The task requires the heuristic to be admissible.
You may skip a ball from the ammo and u can use only the first ball in it each turn.
for now, that's my code:
def successor(self, state):
        """Generates optimized successor states for the given state."""
        line, ammo = state
        successors = []

        if not ammo:
            return []


        balls_count = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        ammo_count = [0, 0, 0, 0]

        for ball in ammo:
            ammo_count[ball - 1] += 1
        for ball in line:
            balls_count[ball - 1] += 1

        # Validate that at least 3 of any color are available
        for i in range(4):
            if balls_count[i] > 0 and balls_count[i] + ammo_count[i] < 3:
                return []

        line_len = len(line)
        first_ball = ammo[0]

        new_ammo = ammo[1:]
        # Insert the first ball at each position in the line
        for i in range(line_len + 1):
            # Skip consecutive balls
            if i < line_len - 1 and line[i] == first_ball:
                if line[i + 1] == first_ball:
                    i = i + 2
                    continue
                i = i + 1
                continue
            
            new_line = line[:i] + (first_ball,) + line[i:]
            reduced_line = self.check_line_sequences(new_line, i, line_len + 1)
            
            new_state = (reduced_line, new_ammo)

            if self.is_redundant(new_state):
                continue

            action = [i, first_ball]
            successors.append((action, new_state))

        # Add the skip option
        skipped_state = (line, new_ammo)

        if not self.is_redundant(skipped_state):
            action = ["skip", first_ball]
            successors.append((action, skipped_state))

        return successors


couldn't find any admissible heuristic, so i put 1 if its not the end of the game and 0 if it is.
problem1 = ((1, 1), (1,))  # 1, t: 0
problem2 = ((1, 2, 2, 1, 1), (2, 1))  # 1, t: 0
problem3 = ((1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1), (3,))  # 1, t: 0
problem4 = ((2, 2, 3, 2), (3, 3))  # 2, t: 0
problem5 = ((2, 2, 3, 2), (3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4))  # 2, t: 0
problem6 = ((2, 2, 3, 3, 2), (1, 3))  # 2, t: 0
problem7 = ((3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3), (3, 4))  # 2, t: 0
problem8 = ((1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1), (2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1))  # 2, t: 0
problem9 = ((2, 3, 3, 2), (1, 2, 3))  # 3, t: 0
problem10 = ((4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1), (4, 3, 4))  # 3, t: 0
problem11 = ((1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1), (3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4))  # 3, t: 0
problem12 = ((2, 2, 3, 3, 1), (1, 1, 2, 3))  # 4, t: 0
problem13 = ((4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2), (1, 3, 4, 4))  # 4, t: 0
problem14 = ((1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 3, 4))  # 4, t: 0
problem15 = ((1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4))  # 4, t: 0
problem16 = ((1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2))  # 4, t: 0.05, 0
problem17 = ((1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1), (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4))  # 4, t: 0.1, 0
problem18 = ((2, 2, 3, 3, 1), (4, 1, 1, 2, 3))  # 5, t: 0
problem18_1 = ((1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1), (4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1))  # 5, t: 0
problem19 = ((1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1), (4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1))  # 5, t: 0
problem20 = ((1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1), (3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4))  # 5, t: 0.25, 0.1
problem21 = ((1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4))  # 5, t: 0.21, 0.05
problem22 = ((1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3))  # 5, t: 0.17, 0.03
problem22_1 = ((1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1))  # 5, t: 0.08, 0.03
problem22_2 = ((1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1), (3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1))  # 6, t: 9.6, 2
problem23 = ((3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3), (3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4))  # 7, t: 0
problem24 = ((1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2))  # 7, t: 0
problem25 = ((3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3), (2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3))  # 7, t: 0.06
problem25_1 = ((1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1), (3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1))  # 7, t: 0.23, 0.06
problem25_2 = ((3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3), (4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3))  # 7, t: 9.6, 7.2
problem26 = ((1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2))  # 8, t: 0.03, 0.01
problem27 = ((1, 2, 1, 2), (1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2))  # 10, t: 0
problem28 = ((2, 2, 3, 2), (3, 1))  # no, t: 0
problem29 = ((4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2), (1, 3))  # no, t: 0
problem30 = ((2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4), (2, 2, 3, 2))  # no, t: 0
problem31 = ((4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2), (1, 3, 4))  # no, t: 0
problem32 = ((4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1), (1, 1, 2, 3))  # no, t: 0
problem50 = ((1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 1), (2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2))

i have those tests for checking and i need it to solve it as quickly as possible with the lowest number of balls to finish.

A Stack Overflow question should be about a narrow, specific technical issue -- not the larger problem you're trying to solve, but a particular place you got stuck while solving that problem yourself, isolated from the original context enough that people who encounter that problem while writing a completely different kind of program can still find and benefit from your question's answers.

"couldn't find any admissible heuristic, so i put 1 if its not the end of the game and 0 if it is." Well, that's technically a heuristic, and it is admissible, but obviously it's not an extremely good heuristic. So, you say you couldn't find any admissible heuristic apart from this one; could you at least find some non-admissible heuristic? If you can, it might be possible to tweak them into admissible heuristics.
